# How to adjust the scale of figures with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of dictionary that I extract from a set of regular expressions. I am plotting the result of every dictionary with using the same function and with looping only the name of the regular expression:

```
def plot_Node_Own_Synchronization_signals_List(Log_File):
    for regular_expression_key in Node_Own_Synchronization.keys():
        #file = open('/home/data/Signal_Synchronization_Statistics/' + str(regular_expression_key) + '.txt', 'w')
        print('regular_expression_key=  ' + str(regular_expression_key))
        #file.write('regular_expression_key=  ' + str(regular_expression_key) + '\n')
        re_value = Node_Own_Synchronization[regular_expression_key]
        print('re_value=  ' + str(re_value))
        #file.write('re_value=  ' + str(re_value) + '\n')
        dict_node_info = loadInfoFrom_Node_Own_Synchronization_signals_List(Log_File, re_value)
        print('dict_node_info=  ' + str(dict_node_info))
        #file.write('dict_node_info=  ' + str(dict_node_info) + '\n')
        #file.close()

        if (bool(dict_node_info) == False):
            print('I am empty')
        else:
            f = plt.figure(1)
            legend = []
            for mac, dico_data in dict_node_info.items():
                legend.append(mac)
                plt.plot(dico_data['timestamp'], dico_data['Counter'])

            plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
            plt.ylabel(regular_expression_key)
            plt.title('signal_synchronization_variation:' + str(regular_expression_key))
            legend_x = 1
            legend_y = 0.5
            legend = plt.legend(legend, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(legend_x, legend_y), prop={'size': 6})
            for legend_handle in legend.legendHandles:
                legend_handle._legmarker.set_markersize(9)
            plt.grid(True)
            f.savefig("/home/data/Signal_Synchronization_Traces/Own_Synchronization_signal_" + str(regular_expression_key) + "-" + str(date.today()) + ".png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

The problem is that with every new execution I have different scale for my figure. Sometimes different curves appears for the same dataset.

[image]

[image]

How could I fix the scale please?  I need to compare the data.

Comment: It seems you are talking about the scale in terms of order of magnitude? What exactly do you want to compare? Absolute values? Qualitative behaviour of the curves? 
If you are interested in the latter, you could simply normalise your curves to some maximum value. You could also add a second y-axis, have a look at https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html .

Comment: @alexblae  yes I am interesting on the Qualitative behaviour of the curves.

Comment: If you are just interested in the qualitative behaviour, just normalise the curves by `plt.plot(dico_data['timestamp'], dico_data['Counter']/max(dico_data['Counter']))`. Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want the same y-scale for every figure. Just add the line `plt.ylim((0,ulim))` to your code (e.g. somewhere around where you set the axis labels and title). Hereby `ulim` is the particular number you want to set your upper y limit to.

Regarding your observation that the data (and thus the y limits automatically set by matplotlib) seem to change at every execution: Is it possible that the log file you are reading from is constantly being written to by some logging process, so that the data you are reading from the file is actually different at every moment?

Comment: The log file is the same. It  does not change.